# Is meta name="verify-v1" essentially google webmaters verification meta?

Tags: google-search-console, meta-tags

If a website uses `meta name="verify-v1"` within the head, does this mean they are using Google Webmaster tools? and is it associated with any other services?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The meta name `verify-v1` used to be associated with Google Webmaster Tools, it is now deprecated and has been replaced with the meta name `google-site-verification`, which now works across Google's services and not just restricted to WMT.

> [List of Webmaster Verification, Ownership and Verify Sites](https://www.bybe.net/list-of-webmaster-verification-ownership-and-verify-sites/)
>
> ```
> <meta name="google-site-verification" content="GOOGLE ID HERE" />
> <meta name="msvalidate.01" content="BING ID HERE" />
> <meta name="alexaVerifyID" content="ALEXA ID HERE" />
> <meta name="norton-safeweb-site-verification" content="NORTON ID HERE" />
> <meta name="wot-verification" content="WOT ID HERE" />
> <meta name="p:domain_verify" content="PINTEREST ID HERE" />
> <meta name="yandex-verification" content="YANDEX ID HERE" />
> <meta name="majestic-site-verification" content="MAJESTIC ID HERE" />
> <meta name="avgthreatlabs-verification" content="AVG ID HERE" />
> <meta name="baidu-site-verification" content="BAIDU ID HERE" />
> ```